# Solve non-homogeneous second order differential equation with non constant coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$f''(x) \frac12\sigma^2 x^2 + f'(x) \alpha x +1 = 0$$
with conditions that $f(x^*) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \infty$.

I have to first find complementary solutions. I divide the homogeneous equation by the coefficient of the second derivatives. Then, by letting $g(x) = f'(x)$, I find $g(x) = A_1x^{-2\alpha /\sigma}$. This implies $f(x) = B_1 \frac{\sigma^2}{-2\alpha + \sigma^2} x^{\frac{-2\alpha + \sigma^2}{\sigma^2}}$.

I guess I need to find another complementary solution and move to a particular solution, but I don't know how to get these. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: It's Cauchy-Euler's differential equation.  You forgeot the constant ofintegration with $f'=g$

Comment: $f=C$ is another solution of the homogeneous DE.

Comment: This equation is of the first order in $f'$.

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x) = A_1x^{-2\alpha /\sigma^2}$$
$$f'(x) = A_1x^{-2\alpha /\sigma^2}$$
$$f(x) = A_1\int x^{-2\alpha /\sigma^2}dx+\color{red}{C}$$
For  $\dfrac {2\alpha }{\sigma^2}\neq 1$ we have:
$$f(x) = A x^{1-2\alpha /\sigma^2}+\color{red}{C}$$
And for the particular solution:
$$f_p=B \ln x$$
Otherwise:
$$f(x) = A \ln x+\color{red}{C}$$
$f(x)= \text {constant}$ is an obvious solution of the homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: And what is wrong ? @IAmAGuest

Comment: We are talking about the homogeneous DE .....@IAmAGuest

Comment: Apologies, I was relying on the special case $=1$.

Comment: No problem @IAmAGuest........................